# Как перенести данные из Microsoft Access в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

У меня такая проблема. На одном компьютере есть данные в Microsoft Access и мне нужно перенести их на свой компьютер с  MySQL, как я могу это сделать?

Comment: [Exporting Access Data to MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-export.html)

Comment: Самый простой вариант - экспорт данных из MS ACCESS в CSV с последующим импортом через LOAD DATA. Либо, как по ссылке, копирование через ODBC-подключение.